# Why does contribution verification display a numeral value rather than a text value

Tags: drupal, payment-processor, recurring-contributions

When a user submits a credit card for a recurring contribution, the verification page displays the following message:

I want to contribute this amount every 1 (s)

What do I need to do to replace the value '1' with the text 'month'?

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.4, Vanco Payment Processor

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Which version of CiviCRM?

Comment: 'recur_frequency_units' option group exists and contains the appropriate list of frequencies.

Comment: 4.4 isn't enough information here - the latest 4.4 point release has changes that are not in earlier versions - so can you specify the exact version. If not the latest point release start by upgrading to it.

Comment: Anyone else parse "every 1 (s)" as "every second"? :)

Answer (score 2):

While it's still clear you've got a bug, I'm pretty sure your issue isn't that you have "1" but rather that the unit--week, month, year--is missing.  The numeral is there in case you wanted to donate quarterly--it would say "3 month(s)". Again, not that this makes it any better.

However, it might help you or whoever diagnose the bug.  Hopefully it's as simple as the payment processor extension not providing the unit back to the receipt/thank-you page.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug I introduced in an attempt to set is_recur to true, so the checkbox would be checked.

Thank you for your help.